# Cython: pipe exception to file and abort explicitly

Tags: cython

I have two questions regarding the usage of Cython.

**1> How can I pipe the raised exceptions into a file?**

I have tried the following method but it doesn't work.

```
$ python python_cython_example.py 2>&1 > /tmp/hello.txt
```

The generated exception will still be printed on screen instead of the file

**2> How can I exit the program within Cython module?**

During debug phrase, I would like to explicitly quit the application but `sys.exit` doesn't work for me. Do I have any other choices?

Answer (score 1):

For the redirect to a file (My reference being https://askubuntu.com/questions/625224/how-to-redirect-stderr-to-a-file):

```
python3 python_cython_example.py 2>hello.txt
```

This is just redirecting stderr (not stdout) to the file. I don't think Cython behaves any differently from Python here.

---

With respect to `sys.exit`, the following works for me:

pyx file:

```
def f():
    import sys
    sys.exit()
```

py file:

```
import pyximport; pyximport.install()
import cy_exc

cy_exc.f()
print("This line is not run")
```

You could also use the builtin `exit()` (which also works for me) but works by a pretty similar mechanism.

The [documentation for `sys.exit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.exit) says that it exits by raising an exception. Therefore, you'll need to ensure that you're not intercepting this exception (e.g. with a catch-all `except:` block). If you're calling it from a `cdef` function not returning an object you'll need to ensure [that Cython knows to check for exceptions](http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/language_basics.html#error-return-values) with an `except` specification. If you're calling it from another thread you may need a different signalling mechanism (but I think the Cython `prange` construct should be able to cope)

If this really doesn't work for you, you could also call [`os._exit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os._exit). This skips all the clean-up that Python would normally do (e.g. flushing and closing open files). It's likely to work in more cases though since it isn't implemented as an exception.